# evaluate script against object

Tags: groovy

I had script inside text file `application.txt`

```
application { 
    title "Template application"
    settings {}
}
```

I evaluated it like this

```
def application = new MainForm()
Binding binding = new Binding()
binding.setVariable("application", application)

GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding)
    evaluate(new File("application.txt"))
```

where my `MainForm` object contains code like this

```
class MainForm {

    def call(Closure cl) {
        cl.delegate = this
        cl()
    }

    def methodMissing(String name, args) {
        if (name == "title") {
            ....
        } else {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

But I decided to get rid of unessesary `application {}` facility inside text file and leave just plain

```
title "Template application"
settings {}
```

The code I used does not work anymore, throwing me `missing method` exception.

```
def application = new MainForm()
Binding binding = new Binding()
binding.setVariable("application", application)

GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding)
    evaluate(new File("application.txt"))
```

How should I change this code in order to make my new approach working? (basically I want to evaluate code as it was in the instance of `application`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found is like this

http://jorgemanrubia.com/2009/10/10/evaluating-code-dynamically-in-groovy/

with wrapping `new File().text` into a `closure` and then delegating it to object